# JOIN одной строки ко всем

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

К примеру есть результат агрегирующей функции из таблицы `A`

```
COUNT(user_id)|
---------------
55
```

и мне нужно присоединить его к таблице `B` ко всем строкам.
Например, таблица `B`:

```
col1 | col2 | colN
------------------
10   | 20   | 0   
15   | 30   | 0   
...
11   | 0    | 0
```

Результат должен быть:

```
col1 | col2 | colN | A.COUNT(user_id)
-------------------------------------
10   | 20   | 0    | 55
15   | 30   | 0    | 55
...
11   | 0    | 0    | 55
```

Думаю что запрос можно написать так:

```
SELECT * FROM B
LEFT JOIN A
ON 1 = 1
```

но я до конца не уверен, что он всегда будет работать правильно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это называется декартово произведение:

```
SELECT * FROM B, A
```

Comment: А что скажете насчет `1 = 1` ?

Comment: Работать будет правильно.

Answer (score 1):

Заморочился этим вопросом. Получилось следующее:

```
SELECT *FROM table_comments,(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users) X;
```

или в общем

```
SELECT *FROM table2,(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table1) X;
```